# In Rails, why are these extra queries being run when saving a record?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, associations

In `$ rails console` I noticed that multiple queries are being run when I save a record:

```
ruby-1.9.2-p180 :001 > ActiveRecord::Base.logger = Logger.new(STDOUT)
 => #<...> 
ruby-1.9.2-p180 :002 > p = Project.first
 Project Load (0.3ms)  SELECT `projects`.* FROM `projects` LIMIT 1
 => #<Project id: 1, category_id: 1, qualified_at: "2011-12-14 15:06:29", ...> 
ruby-1.9.2-p180 :003 > p.qualified_at = Time.now
 => 2011-12-14 10:11:42 -0500 
ruby-1.9.2-p180 :004 > p.save
  SQL (0.2ms)  BEGIN
  SQL (1.5ms)  SHOW TABLES
  AREL (0.3ms)  UPDATE `projects` SET `qualified_at` = '2011-12-14 15:11:42', `updated_at` = '2011-12-14 15:11:47' WHERE `projects`.`id` = 1
  Category Load (0.3ms)  SELECT `categories`.* FROM `categories` WHERE `categories`.`id` = 1 ORDER BY name LIMIT 1
  ProjectPerson Load (0.4ms)  SELECT `project_people`.* FROM `project_people` WHERE (`project_people`.project_id = 1 AND (project_people.is_client = 1)) LIMIT 1
  Person Load (0.3ms)  SELECT `people`.* FROM `people` WHERE (`people`.`id` = 2)
  ProjectTag Load (0.4ms)  SELECT DISTINCT `project_tags`.tag_id FROM `project_tags` WHERE (`project_tags`.project_id = 1)
  SQL (0.5ms)  COMMIT
 => true
```

I don't have before or after filters in my Project model, and I'm not using an Observer. Obviously these queries relate to associations of the Project model, but why are the queries being run? Not sure what else to consider. Thanks.

Comment: It looks like you have validations on your project model that involve Person, Category, and ProjectTag. Can you post your complete model?

Comment: Thanks for the reply, @Violet. No validations in this model, but I figured it out below...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just figured it out... I'm using the sunspot_rails gem and it was updating the index for that record :) These were associations that were referenced in my index definition.

I'll keep the question in case anyone else happens to come across a similar problem.